# Delete data before import

Tags: xml, caching, solr, solr4

I am working with Solr 4.3, on each import, Solr merges the old and the new documents and I get double count:

> Num Docs:   1270
>   Max Doc:    2520

If I delete a document on my input file and I import after deleting and reloading the core :

```
http://solr:8985/solr/collection1/update/?stream.body=<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>&commit=true

http://solr:8985/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&core=collection1
```

I still find this document in my query results.
Can you  help please ?
Thanks

Comment: Are you actually seeing two copies of the document when you search for it? You should not, so it is an important verification.

Comment: Question. Are you using any unique id as advised by Solr documentation? When you import your documents, the existing ones should be overridden as they have the same document id. If you don't have any id, then the import behaviour is correct.